# Show page in popup like image in JQuery Slimbox2

Tags: jquery, slimbox

I want develop to images in popup therefore I used [JQuery slimbox library](http://www.digitalia.be/software/slimbox2). This is working fine.

Now, I want to show page in popup instead of image. E.g. I will show a thumbnail image of Google and when user clicks on it, then show Google page in popup instead of big image.

How can I archive this?

Answer (score 0):

try to use fancybox, it can load raw html like this

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
            $("a").fancybox({
                padding : 1,
                scrolling : 'no',
                autoDimensions : true

            });
        });
```

However i've used it to load pages from my domain and not 3rd parties pages.
Ofcourse redirection to Google should be handled in that HTML.